# How to engineer a power-loss safe RTC time switch?

Tags: c, arduino, microcontroller, arduino-c++, real-time-clock

I'm using a ESP32 with a DS3231 real time clock. The system should automatically switch on and off an output based on a user-programmable time (HH:MM) on a daily basis. The on and off hours/minutes are stored in flash so they are non-volatile. Also, the duration the output stays on is hardcoded.

I'm trying to develop a function which is called each second to check wether the output should be turned on or off based on the current time provided by the DS3231 RTC. This should be safe against misbehaviour if the power fails. So if for example power is temporarily lost in between an on-interval, the output should be set again for the remaining time interval once power is reapplied.

How can I relatively calculate if the current time is in between the on-time interval?

```
const int8_t light_ontime_h = 2; // Hour interval for how long the output should stay on
const int8_t light_ontime_m = 42; // Minute interval for how long the output should stay on
struct tm currenttime; // Current time is stored in here, refreshed somewhere else in the program from RTC
struct tm ontime; // Hours and minutes to turn on are stored in here. Values are loaded from NVS on each reboot or on change. So struct only holds valid HH:MM info, date etc. is invalid

// This is called each second
void checkTime() {
  struct tm offtime;

  offtime.tm_hour = ontime.tm_hour + light_ontime_h;
  offtime.tm_min = ontime.tm_min + light_ontime_m;

  // Normalize time
  mktime(&offtime);

  // Does not work if power is lost and correct hour/min was missed
  if ((currenttime.tm_hour == ontime.tm_hour) && (currenttime.tm_min == ontime.tm_min)) {
    // Turn output on
  } 
  if ((currenttime.tm_hour == offtime.tm_hour) && (currenttime.tm_min == offtime.tm_min)) {
    // Turn output off
  }

}
```

Comment: The DS3231 has an alarm function which you can connect to an interrupt pin. Not sure if i understand your requirement correctly, but why not use that?

Comment: After reading it again, i do not think it is possible when you have only part of your timestamp. You need current day, month, year and so on. Or seconds since a specific time (this would make things a whole lot easier, there are RTC-ICs that keep time in seconds). What happens when you didn't had power for more than 24h?

Comment: Instead of comparing hours, minutes, and seconds separately, it is usually easier to keep time in just seconds since midnight or minutes past midnight.

Comment: how to calculate the remaining time in a time interval is a simple maths question. how is this a programming question?

Comment: @Piglet Sorry, in general it's clear to me how to calculate a time interval. However if I do something like currenttime.tm_hour >= ontime.tm_hour && currenttime.tm_hour <= offtime.tm_hour it would also only work within the same day. If for example I need to switch on at 11pm for 3 hrs, the statement fails.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 The RTC is battery backed so not having power for more than 24 hrs should not be a problem when it comes to timekeeping. I'll give the seconds approach a try as Delta_G suggested.